# Write a program that queries information from three files. Program should ask for user input telephone number, print name, ss number, annual income

Tags: python

The first file contains the names and telephone numbers of a group of people. The second file contains the names and Social Security numbers of a group of people. The third file contains the Social Security numbers and annual income of a group of people.

data1.txt
Bob, 555-1234
Matthew, 555-2345
Mark, 555-3456
Luke, 000-1234
John, 000-2345

data2.txt
Matthew, 000000001
Mark, 000000002
Luke, 000000003
Joe, 000000004

data3.txt
000000001, 55000
000000003, 65000
000000004, 70000
000000007, 10000000

```
 d1 = []
 d2 = []
 d3 = []

data1 = open("data1.txt", "r")
for line in d1:
d1 = line.split(":")
name = d1[0]
number = int(d1[1])
d1.close()

data2 = open("data2.txt", "r")
for line in d2:
d2 = line.split(":")
name = d2[0]
ssnumber = int(d2[1])
d2.close()

data3 = open("data3.txt", "r")
for line in d3:
d3 = line.split(":")
ssnumber = d3[0]
income = d3[1]
d3.close()

l = []
for x in d2:
    for y in d3:
        if x[1] in y:
            l.append((x[0,y]))
        
newfile = []
for x in d1:
    for y in l:
        if x[0] in y:
            newfile.append((x[1], y[0], *y[1]))


tnumber = input("Enter a telephone number including dash: ")

position = 0 
for data in newfile:
    if data[0] == tel:
        position = 1
    
    print("Telephone number:" , tnumber)
    print("Name: ", data[1])
    print("Social Security number ", data[2])
    print("Annual Income: ", data[3])
    
if position == 0:
    print("There is no data for the telephone number entered")
```

After I run my code, I get the prompt for user input of a telephone number, I enter the 7 digit telephone number including the dash (-), but after I press enter the program stops running and there are no errors. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Why do you want to store your data this way in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I would **really** suggest you take a closer look at the code as it has quite a lot of errors.

For starters,

```
data1 = open("data1.txt", "r")
for line in d1:
d1 = line.split(":")
name = d1[0]
number = int(d1[1])
d1.close()
```

1. Here, you are trying to loop in d1 but d1 is an empty list. I think what you are trying to do is this `for line in data1:`
2. you are splitting the line using `:` but it gives a list with a single element, you will get an `index out of range` when you do `d1[1]`
3. you are closing the list and not the actual file (again, typo)

To get you started, here is a sample code that you can build upon

```
d1 = []
d2 = []
d3 = []

#data1.txt = Bob, 555-1234 Matthew, 555-2345 Mark, 555-3456 Luke, 000-1234 John, 000-2345

with open('data1.txt','r') as file1: #this format automatically closes the file
    for line in file1:
        data1 = line.split(" ")      #split using "space"
        d1.append(data1[0])          #append it to the respective list
        d1.append(data1[1])
print(d1)
```

> output: ['Bob,', '555-1234']

Note: In the code above `data1[0]` appends the name with ',' like 'Bob,'.

Modify your code with these suggestions and let me know if you need further help.